# Setting WebRTC video conferencing to my own server

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-conferencing

I've tried an example of setting webRTC on server explained by Muaz Khan.
Here is the [link](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/video-conferencing/#4157350788195549)

here is the code of configuration

```
var config = {
    openSocket: function (config) {
        var SIGNALING_SERVER = 'https://webrtcweb.com:9559/',
            defaultChannel = location.href.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g, '');

        var channel = config.channel || defaultChannel;
        var sender = Math.round(Math.random() * 999999999) + 999999999;

        io.connect(SIGNALING_SERVER).emit('new-channel', {
            channel: channel,
            sender: sender
        });
```

While changing the code for configuration, I'd changed the value of " SIGNALING_SERVER " variable to my own domain like that

```
var SIGNALING_SERVER = 'https://myweb.com:9559/'
```

That code is not working, I've tried other examples too but i couldn't succeed. Please help me that where i'm doing wrong or what should i do as i'm new to WebRTC. Thanks

Comment: is your server a STUN or TURN server? afaik, the signaling server needs to support one of these

Comment: @danwellman I've hosted my website on godaddy.com. i don't know what type they have and there is no information about server in their cpanel too. let me contact them. Thank you for participation :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if they supported it tbh. There are public ones you can use for dev purposes though, e.g. https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933

Comment: yes, its not supported. should i change SIGNALING_SERVER value to listed one server or should i change hosting of files too? Thank you for your responses :)